# How to implement NSScrollView with many text fields on screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have many text fields arranged vertically on the `iPhone` screen. Each field call the keyboard.

The problem is with the fields at the bottom of the screen, because the keyboard pops up and covers them, so the user can not see them.

I've added `UIScrollView` and drag all the text fields on it - but the scrolling does't work.
Should I add some code?

How do I implement the scroll view?

Comment: Take a look a [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/46556/How-To-Use-UIScrollView-in-Your-iPhone-App look at this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a delegate for all the textfields and use the below code as per your requirement
here self.scrMain is my scrollview object

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == txtRegNo) {
        [self.scrMain setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 20) animated:YES];
    }
    if (textField == txtName) {
        [self.scrMain setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 80) animated:YES];
    }
    if (textField == txtMobile) {
        [self.scrMain setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 150) animated:YES];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.scrMain setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.scrMain setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```